# Parametrizing $SU(2)$ with Hermitian matrices

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, rotation, lie-algebra

There is something that is not clear to me

Here is what I know:

- Pauli matrices are $\sigma_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $\sigma_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $\sigma_3 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$
- Each matrix in $A=SU(2)$ can be represented as $\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & -\bar \beta \\ \beta & \bar\alpha\end{pmatrix},\, |\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$ and decomposed as $A=wI-ix\sigma_1-iy\sigma_2-iz\sigma_3$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1$. That is $I,-i\sigma_1,-i\sigma_2, -i\sigma_3$ are sort of a basis for $SU(2)$, but values have to be normalized
- Each matrix in $A=SU(2)$ can be obtained as $A=\exp (H)$ where $H$ is skew Hermitian. Now a basis for skew Hermitian matrices is also $-i\sigma_1,-i\sigma_2, -i\sigma_3$ and $H=-\alpha i\sigma_1-\beta i\sigma_2 -i\gamma \sigma_3$

My question is: is there a simple relation between the parametrization $w,x,y,z\in S^3$ for $$A\in SU(2), A=wI-ix\sigma_1-iy\sigma_2-iz\sigma_3$$ and the parametrization $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in \mathbb{R}^3$ for
$$A\in SU(2), A=\exp (H),H=-\alpha i\sigma_1-\beta i\sigma_2 -i\gamma \sigma_3$$

The question arises because I see often the first parametrization in use (for example as a way to represent unit quaternions) but never the second one

Comment: Reviewed [exponentiation of Pauli vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) yet?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): $H$ is skew-Hermitian rather than Hermitian??

Comment: I think the answer can be found here: [M.Hamada, "On Parameterizations of Rotations"](https://www.tamagawa.jp/research/quantum/bulletin/pdf/Tamagawa.Vol.5-5.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [exponentiating a Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) is straightforward,
 $$A\in SU(2),~~ A=\exp (H), \qquad H=-\alpha i\sigma_1-\beta i\sigma_2 -i\gamma \sigma_3 .$$
Define
$$
\theta ^2\equiv  \alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 , \qquad n_1=\alpha /\theta;\qquad  n_2=\beta /\theta;\qquad n_3=\gamma /\theta ,
$$
so that the antihermitean logarithm of the group element is but 
$$
H= -i\theta~ \vec n \cdot \vec \sigma , ~~ \Longrightarrow ~\exp (H)= \cos \theta -i\sin\theta ~~\vec n \cdot \vec \sigma ~.
$$

That is to say
$$
w=\cos\theta; \qquad x= \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} \alpha ; \qquad  y= \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} \beta ; \qquad z= \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} \gamma ~
$$
a euclidean unit four-vector, alright.